# Increasing plot size in forest plot figure output from metafor package in R

Tags: r, figure, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm plotting a summary forest plot for a multi-factor meta-analysis, and want to highlight the categorical differences between treatments (network legs). While I love how clean the figures are that metafor produces, I'd like to be able to increase the real estate dedicated to the plotted summary effects and confidence intervals, increasing the size of the points without losing the weighting. 
[image: standard forest plot output]

How can I increase the plot size (i.e. "zoom" in on the summary effect points and confidence intervals at scale) so that it occupies more space in the center of the figure and is easier to read? (And to do so without affecting the adjacent text (annotation and labels), or eliminating the weighting.)

I've played around with the cex options, which does increase the size of the plot and summary points, but it also increases the text for the factor descriptions and numeric annotations (Forest 1 cex = 1.55). 
[image: forest plot using cex=1.55 adjustment]

I also tried to increase the point size via psize (Forest 1 psize = 2), but it eliminates the visual representation of the weighting factor. (It also is more of a band aid, I'd really like to increase the size of the plot.)
[image: forest plot with psize=2 adjustment]

```
forest(fit$beta, sei=fit$se, slab=labels, annotate=TRUE, cex = 1, 
    cex.main = 1.5, cex.lab = 1, cex.axis = 1, cex.sub = 3, 
    efac = 1.25, 
    xlim = c(-1000, 750), alim = c(-100, 100), ylim = c(-1, 19), 
    xlab="Standardized Mean Difference", 
    rows=c(15:13, 10:7, 4:1), 
    main="Forest 1 Standard")
text(-1000, c(16, 11, 5), pos=4, 
  c("No Water Stress", "Moderate Water Stress", "Severe Water Stress"), font=2)
text(c(-1000, 300), c(18, 18), pos=4, 
   c("Treatment (Factor Combination)", "Summary Effect [95% CI]"), font=2)
```

Comment: You need to reduce the values of `xlim` (bring them closer to 0).

Answer (score 1):

Set graphwidth=unit(10,"cm") or accordingly in the forestplot() function